# ASP.NET Core pre-fill IFormFile with previously uploaded file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have an asp.net core razor page that allows user to upload a file. I do this with a `[BindProperty]` for an `IFormFile` and i store it in a db as a `byte[]`. This works well.

However when the user refreshes/goes back to the upload page i want to fill it out with the info he/she put in earlier - this also works well for e.g. strings but not for IFormFile. I can set it, but the `<input asp-for="Input.Icon" type="file">` still produces an input field that says "No file selected"

How do i fix it so that the previously uploaded file is already selected for the user?

Razor page .cshtml:

```
<input asp-for="Input.Icon" type="file">
```

PageModel:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public MyInputModel Input { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    var existing = GetPreviouslyUploadedInputModel()
    if (existing != null)
    {
        Input.Description = existing.Description;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(existing.Icon))
        {
            Input.Icon = new FormFile(memoryStream, 0, existing.Icon.Length, "Icon", "FileName");
        }

        ModelState.Clear();
    }
}
```

MyInputModel:

```
public class MyInputModel
{
    [StringLength(maximumLength: 4000)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public IFormFile Icon { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You cannot do this. The browser’s security system does not allow this. I’d suggest you to show the previously uploaded data in some other way and then only offer the user to select a file to _replace_ the previously stored data (i.e. if the `IFormFile` is filled, replace the data, otherwise keep it).

Comment: @poke Thank you! I did not know this. Good suggestion about offering the user to replace an image if one is already present. Probably means i'll have to remove the `[Required]` annotation from the model and handle the validation in code but its definitely doable